# Estimating mean and prediction intervals for new predictions using meta-regression output

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

Let's start with linear regression. You develop a simple linear regression equation $y = ax + b$. You can predict $\hat{y}_h$ for $x_h$ and estimate the prediction intervals using

$$\hat{y}_h \pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \times s \times \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_h - \bar{x})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$$

Let's move onto meta-regression. Let's say we use meta-regression to develop the equation $y = a(m - x) + b$. How do we estimate the prediction intervals for $\hat{y}_h$ when $x = x_h$?

So far I have found this equation from Spinelli and Pandis (2019)

$M \pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2},k-2} \times \sqrt{T^2 + V_M}$

where $M$ is the mean effect size, $T^2$ is the heterogeneity and $V_M$ is the variance of mean effects.

To me, this is the equation for the prediction interval for the equation developed by the research, and not the equation you should use when making a prediction, primarily because I cannot see where $x_h$ is actually used in this equation. However, the publication with the equation contains these variables which makes me think I am missing something.

If this equation is not correct, can someone please provide me with the correct equation? And if, like linear regression, there is a difference between simple and multiple linear regression, please provide the equation for multiple linear regression?

Also, new to LaTex so if someone can please assist by fixing that equation that would be great.